# MongoDb add property and move items from other

Tags: mongodb

I have an object like this

```
{
name : "test"
data : [{"itemcode":"a1"},{"itemcode":"a2"}]
}
```

I need to change to

```
{
name : "test"
shops :[ 
  { "shopid" : 1,
    "data" : [{"itemcode":"a1"},{"itemcode":"a2"}]
}]
}
```

I try to update but I can not copy the array it still ramain empty. To update I use

```
db.getCollection("shop").find({}).forEach(function(doc){
var a = doc.data;
var s = [{
    "shopid":NumberInt(1),
    "data": a}]

db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need assign array to doc.shops.

```
db.getCollection("shop").find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    var a = doc.data;
    doc.shops = [{
        "shopid":NumberInt(1),
        "data": a}];

    delete doc.data;

    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```